# C# window height only gets bigger, not smaller

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide

I've got a form with a collapsible group box (got it from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12835/XP-Style-Collapsible-GroupBox).  I'm using it basically to show/hide advanced options on the form.  The group-box itself is not at issue, however, as I did the same thing with just a regular `Panel` that I changed the Visible property on and the issue is the same:

When I hide this box, I want the window to shrink accordingly.  So I've got code when you click on the box header that basically goes like:

```
if (OptionsPanel.IsCollapsed)
    this.Height -= (OptionsPanel.Height - OptionsPanel.CollapsedHeight);
else
    this.Height += (OptionsPanel.Height - OptionsPanel.CollapsedHeight);
```

The problem is- when you expand the box, the window does indeed grow accordingly, but when you collapse the box, it doesn't shrink.  In fact, nothing I do seems able to make the window smaller - I've even tried hard-coding the window sizes, and it never gets smaller, only bigger.

Is there something I'm missing to make this work?  Or is there a better component out there that will do this right?  Honestly I'm shocked that there isn't a default control in the Toolbox for doing this sort of thing, as it seems like a fairly common thing to do, and I've seen things like this on a lot of forms.  Doesn't seem like the kind of thing you should have to go to 3rd party plugins or roll your own code for.

Comment: Is the form `AutoSize` proeprty set to `true`? Also, have you checked that the code is actually called when collapsing, using breakpoint or debug-print, etc?

Comment: Code is definitely reached.  Checked all paths with breakpoints.  As for AutoSize, see response below.  Not sure why it's not working, but what I'm doing now is just disabling the section instead of hiding it.  Not what I'd prefer, but may suffice for now.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try adding  AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink property?

Preferably, both AutoSize=true, AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink

In C#

```
OptionsPanel.AutoSize = true;
OptionsPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autosizemode.aspx

Comment: Note that this can also be done in design mode via the properties panel.

Comment: Looked promising, but that makes the whole thing completely disappear when you hide the panel, including the button to make it reappear, so you can't get it back open.  It would probably work if I could get it to autosize only on height, not width, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that...

Comment: If the button is outside the panel, then it should not disappear. Is it possible for you to post the main window XAML?

Comment: I'm not using XAML - it's all done in the Forms Designer.  The button in this case was the header for the collapsible group box, rather than an actual button.  (See the link I posted above - it's not my code.)  I tried just making a panel that turns invisible, but then the form doesn't change size at all, either larger or smaller.  I just get a blank space where it used to be.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Form's [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx) is set to True and [`AutoSizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosizemode.aspx) set to [`GrowAndShrink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autosizemode.aspx) the default is [`GrowOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autosizemode.aspx)

[image]

Comment: well, I don't get the resize cursor. When I maximize it grows ok. When I restore it keeps the maximized size but the windows is as restored. Therefore the window can only grow in my case..

Comment: This actually worked! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571041/whats-preventing-me-from-resizing-downsizing-my-windows-form-object in my case I do the exact opposite of your answer and works! :D

Comment: @Totty.js This is perhaps my favorite comment on stack overflow of all time, especially since doing the exact opposite worked for me as well.